# Chroma key removal algorithm/library

Tags: c#, .net, graphics, computer-vision

I am working on a recorder software for desktop PC that works on Windows XP/7.  I would like to be able to remove backgrounds from the recorded video by means of chroma keying.

[image: Example]
<sub>(source: [kudlian.net](http://www.kudlian.net/products/screen/images/0002-large.jpg))</sub>

Any info of such algorithms, complete libraries, open source projects?  I need it to be accessible from c#, and preferably something that will run on GPUs (CUDA, pixel shaders, ...)

My video is accessible in RGB24 and YUY2 formats, so it would be great if such library will be able to handle those formats.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A good starting point is to study the solution provided on this [blog](http://www.quasimondo.com/archives/000615.php). The color separation approach described there is a good baseline algorithm. 
However, relying on color alone may be sub-optimal is some situations (high subject movement, clothing color conflicts etc.). If you want something very robust, you will need to start looking at contour segmentation techniques (a.k.a [active contours](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_contour_model)).

Comment: I am also looking for a solution that would do 'static background removal' - any link to spare?

Comment: try this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2100064/how-to-remove-background-image-and-get-fore-image